# MailboxAddress can't be created using variables (C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mailkit

I am creating an android application using Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to run an automated email feature that sends emails when a user registers an account with my application. I am using the NuGet package MailKit for this.

```
var mailSender = new MailboxAddress("useremail@gmail.com");
```

When I use this code, it creates the MailboxAddress perfectly fine and I can send an email to the address I have specified without any errors. However when I use this code:

```
string email = getEmail.Text;
var mailSender = new MailboxAddress(email);
```

I am going into break mode with an unhandled exception. The variable email definitely has a value in it which I have inspected whilst debugging.

Any idea as to why it wouldn't let me create this object using a variable instead of a hard coded string?

Thanks

Comment: Does the exception give any more details?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis nah it doesn't i'm afraid

Comment: It seems to parse the address and [throw an exception](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/MailboxAddress.cs#L207) if it isn't correct. What is te value you're trying to stick in there?

Answer (score 2):

The MailboxAddress .ctor that takes only a single string is meant to only accept "user@domain"-style addresses. If you plan to pass in user-entered text, then you need to use `MailboxAddress.Parse()`